# Values in FormData Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multipartform-data, form-data

How can I see the key-value values ​​that I have in a FormData when I capture it in this way:

```
var formdata = new FormData (form);
```

When I print in the Deveploment Tolols console this way:

```
e.preventDefault ();
var form = $ ('# frmSede') [0];
var formdata = new FormData (form);
var oEstado = new FormData (document.forms.namedItem ("state"));
console.log ("The state is:" + oEstado);
```

I printed on the screen, the following:

```
[object FormData]
```

I would like to see the values ​​of each value in the key-value in order to add a logic before sending the data to a rest service. Thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting it explicitly to the string. Try comma:

```
console.log ("The state is:", oEstado);
```

This will not properly work in old browsers like ie9 etc., for all other cases this should be enough